# Adding items selected from dropdown into a list using Javascript DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to add selected items from the dropdown into a shopping list using `<li>`.
But my code gives the error `Uncaught ReferenceError display is not defined at HTMLSelectElement.onchange`. Can someone help fixing it?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <select id="select_item" onchange="display(this)">
        <option value="NoteBook">Notebook</option>
        <option value="Jello">Jello</option>
        <option value="Spinach">Spinach</option>
        <option value="Rice">Rice</option>
        <option value="Birthday Cake">Birthday Cake</option>
        <option value="Candles">Candles</option>
    </select>

    <p>Shopping Cart:</p>
    <ul id="shopList"></ul>

    <script>
        // method 2
        var options = document.querySelectorAll("option");
        console.log(options[0]);

        for(var i=0; i< options.length; i++){
            option.addEventListener('change', function display(e){
                console.log(e.target.value);
            })
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You do not have the `option` variable defined. Check line `option.addEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

There is no `display` function defined which you use on you html select element.You can get the selected value onchange following way

```js
function display (v) {
   console.log(v)
}
```

```html
<select id="select_item" onchange="display(this.value)">
        <option value="NoteBook">Notebook</option>
        <option value="Jello">Jello</option>
        <option value="Spinach">Spinach</option>
        <option value="Rice">Rice</option>
        <option value="Birthday Cake">Birthday Cake</option>
        <option value="Candles">Candles</option>
    </select>
```